# Oop PHP login checking hashed password

Tags: php, pdo

My problem is checking hashed password in class.
This is error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in Auth.php:51 Stack trace: #0 index.php(19): Auth->login() #1 {main} thrown in Auth.php on line 51

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    #LINE 19

    $ui->login($username, $password); 
}
```

Here my code

```
public function login ( $username, $password ) {
    $u_login = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE username = :username");
    $u_login->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $u_login->execute();
    $u_login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    # LINE 51
    $u_v_PASS = password_verify($password, $u_login['password']);  
    if($u_v_PASS->count()) {
        echo 'uspesno';
    } else { 
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you check both values on 1 query ?

Comment: @Vidal how to do query?

Comment: There's an answer below, did you try that?

Comment: Why did you include `->count()` in the conditional statement for? There's no need for it. Just use a regular conditional. You'd also should have gotten an error for it; enable error reporting. This looks like a typographical error to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing a fetch with your PDOStatement object but not storing the result of that fetch. Instead you are looking for the password in the PDOStatement object itself. Try:

```
public function login ( $username, $password ) {
    $u_login = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE username = :username");
    $u_login->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $u_login->execute();

    /*
     * Now that the prepared statement has been built and executed, we can
     * try to fetch a matching user and store it as $user - this will be an
     * array if successful or boolean false if not.
     */
    $user = $u_login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /* Check that $user is not false and the password_verify returns boolean
     * true when comparing the password to the hashed password stored in the
     * database.
     */
    if ($user && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
        // User was found and password matched
    }
}
```